# Accessing Grid inside ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have ControlTemplate with Grid inside. But i can't find any way to access this Grid in controls, that contain my template :(

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="CertificatesTable">
        <Grid Margin="5">
            ...
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="100" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#99000000">
    <ContentControl Name="Certificates1" Template="{StaticResource CertificatesTable}"/>
</Border>
<Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="100" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#99000000">
    <ContentControl Name="Certificates2" Template="{StaticResource CertificatesTable}"/>
</Border>
<Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="100" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#99000000">
    <ContentControl Name="Certificates3" Template="{StaticResource CertificatesTable}"/>
</Border>
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "access".  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pomah welcome to stack-overflow.

Here is simple code how to access or get grid details in code side.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Name="myControl" TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="CertificatesTable">
        <Grid Margin="5" x:Name="grv">
            ...
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

C# Code to access grid details-

```
ar template = myControl.Template;
var myControl = (Grid)template.FindName("grv", myControl);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but i had to call ApplyTemplate() for my controls, because FindName() returned null.